# Ruby On Rails TCPSocket

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sockets, connection

I developed a server in C++ and I would like to develop an interface in Ruby On Rails.

So I started to read http://ruby.railstutorial.org/, meanwhile I start looking if I would be able to create a connection between my Ruby On Rails application and my server.
I find out I could use TCPSocket.

My question is : Could I open just 1 TCPSocket by session (and store it somewhere) ?
Or would I have to open a TCPSocket for every action in my controllers ?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: What is wrong with opening a TCP connection for each request for starters? I think it will make things a lot easier and you can still think about performance tweaks later on, should you notice that this is are a real problem.

Answer (score 0):

app/models/conn.rb:

```
class Conn
  @connection = "foo" # Connect here

  def self.get_connection
    @connection
  end
end
```

Rails console:

```
irb(main):002:0> Conn.get_connection
=> "foo"
```

But unless your server is single-threaded you will have more than one connection anyways.

Comment: The connection will be shared with every sessions, I want to create one connection per session.

Comment: Session is not normally tied to any specific rails instance so there is no way to tell where you end up and store connection there.